# Assembly.LoadFrom with Binding Policies and Resolve Handler

Tags: c#, .net, clr, .net-assembly

the whole situation is a bit complicated, so just stay with me for a while to get the context... Let's say we have some assemblies:

- A BaseClass is defined within BaseClass.dll in Version 1.0.0.0
- A DerivedClass is defined within DerivedClass.dll in Version 1.0.0.0

The main application loads the DerviedClass.dll assembly via `Assembly.LoadForm()` from a path outside the application base and tries to get its types via `GetTypes()`, that is,

```
Assembly derived = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"..\otherdir\DerivedClass.dll");
Type[] foundTypes = derived.GetTypes();
```

If the BaseClass.dll assembly is located next to the DerivedClass.dll (that is both assemblies are in `..\otherdir`, everything works as expected.

Next, delete the `BaseClass.dll` which yields a LoaderException. To get more information about this, add an AssemblyResolve Handler

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolver;
```

which simply writes the requested assembly and its version to the console, that is

```
public static Assembly AssemblyResolver(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Resolving " + args.Name + " from " + args.RequestingAssembly);
    return null;
}
```

As expected, the AssemblyResolver is called with `args.Name` is equal to `BaseClass, Version=1.0.0.0, ...`.

Now, recompile the BaseClass.dll with Version 2.0.0.0 and put it to `otherdir`. 
**By same strange reason this works already. Shouldn't DerivedClass.dll expect Version 1.0.0.0 and refuse to work with Version 1.0.0.0?**

Moreover, if we add an application configuration which redirects the BaseClass from version 1.0.0.0 to version 2.0.0.0, that is,

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="BaseClass"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

and delete the BaseClass.dll again (which yields a LoaderException), the AssemblyResolver is still called with `args.Name` is equal to `BaseClass, Version=1.0.0.0, ...`. **Shouldn't at least now the version be `Version=2.0.0.0`?**

Can anybody explain to me, why changing the version of BaseClass.dll doesn't yield to an error? And why the AssemblyResolver is not called with version 2.0.0.0?

--- EDIT ---
One more interesting fact: With all assemblies having strong name and a publisher policy configuration file, Assembly.LoadFrom only works if there is a version 2.0.0.0 being found, even if there is a version 1.0.0.0 available and the DerivedClass.dll was built with version 1.0.0.0.

However, the AssemblyResolver is still called with version 1.0.0.0.

To me, it looks like the publisher policy is not applied when the AssemblyResolver for LoadFrom Assemblies is called. Is this possible?

Comment: If the reference to other assemblies is not to strong named assemblies, they'll bind to whatever version they find.

Comment: But the reference to other assemble is to a strong named assembly. Moreover, why isn't my AssemblyResolve called with the version after the publisher policy has been applied?

Comment: Without further investigation (that I don't have the time for - sorry about that), I don't know what else to say. If you haven't yet, you could take a look at [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yx7xezcf.aspx).

Comment: No problems about that. I have checked a bit further and updated my original post. The AssemblyResolver is always called with the built version, ignoring the publisher policy completely.

Comment: You can always read that configuration section through the configuration API and do the redirects yourself, if that's what you want to do.

Comment: Sure, but it's kind of the opposite behavior to the CLR which calls my AssemblyResolver with the publisher policy applied when not finding a reference. In the end, two opposite behaviors.